# IOS: error in HomeDirectory

Tags: ios, xcode, home-directory

I have this code

```
NSString *nextSequentialFile =
    [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:photoNumber
    withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (index + 1)]
    options:NSBackwardsSearch
    range:[filePath rangeOfString:photoNumber options:NSBackwardsSearch]];
```

but I have this error and I don't understand beacuse it happens.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *nextSequentialFile =
[filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:photoNumber
withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (index + 1)]
options:NSBackwardsSearch
range:NSMakeRange(0, filePath.length)];
```

Comment: range:NSRangeFromString(filePath)]; //Range or index out of bounds'

Comment: Try using `NSMakeRange(0, filePath.length)` instead of `NSRangeFromString`.  See edits.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `rangeOfString:photoNumber` is out-of-range.  I would recommend logging each of the values you pass to this method in order tell which is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Never assume that methods like `rangeOfString:options:` return a valid range. From the docs:

> **Return Value**
>
> An NSRange structure giving the location and length in
>   the receiver of the first occurrence of aString, modulo the options in
>   mask. **Returns {NSNotFound, 0} if aString is not found or is empty (@"").**
>
> [Emphasis added]

So obtain the range first and check for `NSNotFound` before attempting to use it.